# Kinetic scrolling with libinput possible?

Tags: manjaro, touchpad, libinput

I am using Manjaro like this guy: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-enable-kinetic-scrolling-with-libinput-driver/36488 And my system comes with libinput. Unfortunately libinput does not have kinetic scrolling out of the box. Is it possible to enable it?

An alternative that I used before was synaptics, which has inferior palm rejection instead. But I am thinking about still switching back. So is this one a pick your poison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me reword my askubuntu answer [to the similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1091498/266507#kinetic-scrolling-in-ubuntu)

---

There's a technical reason why libinput didn't implement it. [It's part of FAQ](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faqs.html#kinetic-scrolling-does-not-work), which in particular has a link to [this bugreport](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38909). TL;DR of which: kinetic scrolling being implemented in synaptics turned out to be a design mistake. It led to nasty bugs, such as that if you scrolled, and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> before scroll stopped, the app you're scrolling would trigger zoom-in or zoom-out. It's because kinetic scrolling is implemented by continuous sending of scrolling events, and the app have no way to differ real and fake scroll events.

Worse: the proper way to implement that is in GUI toolkits, i.e. GTK+ and Qt *(and maybe EFL, though it's little known outside of Enlightement Desktop Environment)*, but if you have kinetic scrolling in driver + kinetic scrolling in toolkit — you can expect this to end up in mess.

GTK+ have implemented kinetic scrolling, e.g. it works for me in `evince` app, version 3.30 for evince, and 3.24 for GTK.

Qt I don't know. I found [some blog-post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/07/19/kinetic-scrolling-on-any-widgets/) saying that kinetic scrolling was implemented for everything in 2009, but I can't reproduce it in Okular, nor Qutebrowser, nor Kate, so it's definitely untrue.

Comment: Unlike the synaptics driver, libinput also has access to keyboard events, it can easily stop the coasting when a new event is arrived.

Comment: @rustyx however it can't do anything if a user moved a cursor elsewhere while kinetic movement is ongoing. So it may result in unintended scroll of a widget that you didn't actually scroll.

Comment: I did not found a bug report for that, so I created it: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=456383